# How to merge matching/unmatching elements two SQL tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

This been asked before BUT not exactly to my need. Here is what I am trying to do. I am using Oracle SQL. I have two tables with some disjoint and some matching elements. I want them to merge with condition that Table-B should supersede if there is match of MID element(first column).

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A ( MID VARCHAR2(255), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(300) );
CREATE TABLE TABLE_B ( MID VARCHAR2(255), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(300) );
-- Table A
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ( 'M-003', 'ABC03' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ( 'M-004', 'ABC04' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ( 'M-005', 'ABC05' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ( 'M-006', 'ABC06' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ( 'M-007', 'ABC07' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ( 'M-008', 'ABC08' );
-- Table B
INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES ( 'M-001', 'ABC01' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES ( 'M-002', 'ABC02' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES ( 'M-003', 'ABC03' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES ( 'M-004', 'DEF04' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES ( 'M-009', 'ABC09' );
INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES ( 'M-010', 'ABC10' );
```

Table_A

```
M-003   ABC03
M-004   ABC04
M-005   ABC05
M-006   ABC06
M-007   ABC07
M-008   ABC08
```

Table_B

```
M-001   ABC01
M-002   ABC02
M-003   ABC03
M-004   DEF04
M-009   ABC09
M-010   ABC10
```

Desired result:

```
M-001   ABC01
M-002   ABC02
M-003   ABC03
M-004   DEF04
M-005   ABC05
M-006   ABC06
M-007   ABC07
M-008   ABC08
M-009   ABC09
M-010   ABC10
```

Below didn't work;

```
SELECT A.MID, A.DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLE_A A, TABLE_B B
WHERE TABLE_A.MID != TABLE_B.MID
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B;
```

How do I achieve this by using Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 2):

A way you could get the results you're looking for is by using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `COALESCE`:

```
Select          Coalesce(B.MID, A.MID)                 As MID, 
                Coalesce(B.DESCRIPTION, A.DESCRIPTION) As DESCRIPTION
From            Table_A A
Full Outer Join Table_B B   On  A.MID = B.MID
;
```

Comment: Why not use a **FULL** outer join, and do away with the `UNION`?

Comment: @mathguy I thought about that at first, but I wasn't sure if oracle supported `FULL JOIN`s.  If it does, that would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: It does. That is indeed a cleaner solution: no need to scan `table_b` a second time, and no need for expensive `UNION` (which must de-duplicate, a non-trivial task on large data).

Comment: Note: (I didn't know this, I just noticed playing with this example.) If you use the USING syntax for joins, that will already `coalesce` `A.MID` and `B.MID` for you. That is: `...from A full outer join B using (MID)`. Of course, then you `select MID` - when you use this syntax, the resulting column can't be qualified with `A` or `B`.

Comment: In real db, I have more than 2 columns(16 to be exact). Above solution doesn't work for more than two columns. Adding 3rd Coalesce statement gives error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.  Any solution to this situation?

Comment: @jane - this query (modified appropriately) should work for any number of columns. The error message you received is likely to be caused by you forgetting to put a comma before the third COALESCE (or perhaps before the fourth or the fifth - the error message should tell you EXACTLY where something unexpected happened).

Comment: My mistake, you are right,  I had forgotten ',' -sorry about that and thanks!